# code first one-to-one enable cascade delete

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have one to one relationship with foreign keys but the `Cascade Delete` is not enabled for some reason. The sample code is below.

```
public class AppRegistration
{
    public int AppRegistrationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string StudentOrAgent { get; set; }
    // navigation properties
    public virtual AppStatus AppStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual Agreement Agreement { get; set; }
    public virtual AnotherTable AnotherTable { get; set; }
}
```

The dependent table with a foreign key is below.

```
public class Agreement
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("AppRegistration")]
    public int AppRegistrationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAgreed { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRegistration AppRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to delete an entry from the generated `AppRegistrations` table I get a Reference constraint conflict.

I tried putting `[Required]` on the navigation property in the dependent table but it doesn't do anything - the `Update-Database` command shows the `No pending code-based migrations.` message. Any ideas? Thanks.

**Update:**
I'm getting the following error message:

`The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.AppStatus_dbo.AppRegistrations_AppRegistrationId". The conflict occurred in database "MVCapp", table "dbo.AppStatus", column 'AppRegistrationId'.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I decided to work out the `cascade delete` problem in a separate sample project. I found the following blog & MSDN pages very useful.

- http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671256%28v=VS.103%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671273%28v=VS.103%29.aspx

Using the `Code First` approach create the following Model.

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
public class Book
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public string BookAuthor { get; set; }
    public string BookISBN { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

(I realize the entity names suggest one-to-many relationship, but I am trying to model 1-to-1 relationship, as in my original question at the top.)

So, in the above model each **Category** can only have one **Book**.

In your `DbContext`-derived class add the following.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
        .HasKey(t => t.CategoryId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.Book)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Category)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

(The following namespaces are required for the above code: `System.Data.Entity`, `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions`.)

This properly creates the 1-to-1 relationship. You'll have a primary key in each table and also a foreign key in `Book` table with `ON DELETE CASCADE` enabled.

[image: Database Diagram for the model]

In the above code, on the `Category` entity I used `WithRequiredPrincipal()` **with** `t => t.Category` argument, where the argument is the foreign key column in the dependent table.

If you use `WithRequiredPrincipal()` **without** an argument you'll get an extra column in the `Book` table and you'll have two foreign keys in the `Book` table pointing to `CategoryId` in `Category` table.

I hope this info helps.

**UPDATE**

Later on I found answer directly here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#RequiredToRequired

Answer (score 7):

A reason why you're not getting cascading delete is because your relationship is optional.

If you want the relationship required i.e. an `AppRegistration` has to have one `Agreement` you can use (cascading delete configured automatically):

```
public class Agreement
{
    ...
    [Required]
    public AppRegistration AppRegistration{ get; set; }
}
```

If you want the relationship to be optional with cascading delete you can configure this using Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppRegistration>()
    .HasOptional(a => a.Agreement)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried putting `[Required]` but the code-migration's `Update-Database` returns `No pending code-based migrations.` Any way to get around this?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you wouldn't want to try the first technique, because it's nearly impossible to satisfy a one-to-one relationship that is required in both directions.  If you try to insert Agreement, you will get a constraint violation because AppRegistration does not exist, and vice versa.

Comment: @user2291748 Did you add a migration before running update-database? AaronLS, hmm maybe you're right, it's just something that came to mind.

Comment: @MattSull87 I did add migration. I've used update-database several times already before I ran into the issue.

Comment: running the Fluent API code inside the `OnModelCreating()` added a column in the `AppRegistrations` table and marked it as a foreign key. But foreign key should be in the `Agreements` table instead.

Comment: Actually there is a foreign key already in the `Agreements` table but it doesn't do cascading delete.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is if you drop and recreate the db, add an initial migration and in the initialmigration.cs file look for `CreateTable("dbo.Agreement")` and in that look for `.ForeignKey` and see if `cascadeDelete:` is set to true or false.

Comment: The `cascadeDelete` is not even mentioned there.