# Fluent API not cascading on delete in a one-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public long StudentId { get; set; }
    public StudentDetails details { get; set; }
}

public class StudentDetails
{
    public long StudentDetailsId { get; set; }
    public Student student{ get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

One student contains one studentdetails. A studentdetails can not exist without a corresponding student.

With these mappings:

```
    public StudentMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("Student");

        this.HasKey(x => x.StudentId);

        this.HasRequired(x => x.details)
            .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.student)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }

    public StudentDetailsMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("StudentDetails");

        this.HasKey(x => x.StudentDetailsId);

        this.HasRequired(x => x.student);
    }
```

However, when I go to the database in SQL Management Studio, and do the following: `DELETE FROM STUDENTS WHERE StudentId == 1`, the Student row gets deleted, but the delete does not cascade to the studentdetails row. What's going wrong? I am trying to get the StudentDetails row to get deleted when I delete it's Student parent object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485831/code-first-one-to-one-enable-cascade-delete) SO and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#RequiredToRequired) article on MSDN?

As I can see, your model is not a real one-on-one relationship because the two entities you have here doesn't share the **same** primary key.

When you model a relationship like that you are, in fact, creating a one-to-many table structure in database: how can you prevent that StudentDetailsId will not be in use for another student? I mean, you can enforce it with a business rule, but strictly db speaking there no rule.

If you want to enforce cascade delete with EF in a one-to-one, you need to make something like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public long StudentId { get; set; }
    public StudentDetails details { get; set; }
}

    public class StudentDetails
    {
        public long StudentId { get; set; }
        public Student student{ get; set; }
        //other properties
    }

public StudentMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("Student");

        this.HasKey(x => x.StudentId);

        this.HasRequired(x => x.details)
            .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.student)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }

    public StudentDetailsMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("StudentDetails");

        this.HasKey(x => x.StudentId);

        this.HasRequired(x => x.student);
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This helped me out, thanks. I need to read up on how EF code first models different relationship multiplicity types!